# Integration with facebook

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, cocoa-touch

I want to send my App request to my facebook friends in my iphone Applicaion.I get facebook friends on my table view .want send them join my app in iphone which friend i will choose in table view. Please give me suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: i was try send them link on them walls i think its not good way.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the [Facebook iOS SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk). there are examples and more info there for hooking up your app to Facebook.